# How to fix error [filter:notarray] Expected array but received json on Angularjs table filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to put together my first AngularJS page. This table reads its data from an `$http` call receiving json. The iteration works fine and the table displays as expected, until I include  `| filter:searchitem` in the `ng-repeat` for `users`. At that point I get

> Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {.....}

I read all the questions that seemed similar and couldn't find anyone that I was able to apply to this case. The iteration `ng-repeat="user in users"` works fine without the filter so `users` seems to be of the right format.

This is the relevant code. Thanks for any assistance.

```
<script >
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('studentController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.searchitem   = '';     // set the default search/filter term
    $scope.users = [];

    //Get List   
    $http({ method: 'GET',      url: 'serve-products.php'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) { $scope.users = response.data;}, function errorCallback(response) { alert("Error. Try Again!"); });

    //Update list
    $scope.refreshUser = function(user) {    $http({    method: 'GET',
        url: 'serve-products.php?d=' + user.code
        }).then(function successCallback(response) { $scope.users = response.data;}, function errorCallback(response) { alert("Error. Try Again!"); });  };

}]);
</script>

<body class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="studentController" >

    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchitem"  >
      </div>      
    </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Stock</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:searchitem ">
          <td> {{user.code}}   </td>
          <td> {{user.name}} </td>
          <td> <span ng-class="{'st0': user.stocktext == 'OUT OF STOCK'}"> {{user.stocktext}} </span></td>
          <td> 
              <span ng-repeat="(key,value) in user.stock">
                <span class="st{{value}}">{{key}}</span> 
              </span>
          </td>  
          <td> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="refreshUser(user)">Refresh</button> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody> 
    </table>

  </body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not receiving an object with an array of objects (the users)? What type does `$scope.users` has (it must be an array for filter to work)? Maybe you could add a piece of your data, it would be easier for us to test.

Comment: yes, @AdrianPop, the `serve-products.php` script json-encodes a multidimensional associative array so it arrives as an object. Any idea how can I modify the code for filter to work?. Thanks

Comment: You should iterate thorough all the objects inside the bigger object and add them individually to `$scope.users`. Then, you'll have an array of objects and the filter should work. If you can edit your post with a glimpse of how the object looks like, we can also help you debug if future errors occurs. Cheers!

Comment: @AdrianPop I fixed it by encoding a sequential array on the origin of the data: `echo json_encode(array_values($prods));`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great. I guess an "official" response is not needed anymore